# Implement refresh button in Yii for a CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have a CGridView and I'd like to put a button to refresh.

I've tried adding AjaxButton but I couldn't make it.

The grid ID is session-grid.

I have a partial view with only the CGridView.

I managed to get it working but it's duplicated, the original stays there. I am missing anything?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Chosen:

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initRefresh',<<<JS
    $('#update-grid-button').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#session-grid').yiiGridView('update');
    });
JS
,CClientScript::POS_READY);

  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Actualizar',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'icon'=>'repeat white',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
      'id'=>'update-grid-button',
      'class'=>'pull-right',
    )
  )); 
?>
```

Comment: Share what you've done till now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<button id="refresh-button">Refresh!</button>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initRefresh',<<<JS
    $('#refresh-button').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#session-grid').yiiGridView('update');
    });
JS
,CClientScript::POS_READY); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't I just use CHTML::AjaxButton with parameters?

Comment: You can't use an AJAX button. Yii's GridView will perform the AJAX request for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to use the button, http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/43377-how-to-refresh-cgridview/page__view__findpost__p__205994 but since I was having only to set options for ajax, I didn't like it. I prefer your solution registering JS, that way I can manage other JQuery things like ajaxStart().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.fn.yiiGridView.update('session-grid');`

Example:

```
$("#my_button" ).click(function() {
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('session-grid');
});
```

Comment: This will reset filters and pagination as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function update(mygrid)
{
   var $form = $("<form action=\"\" data-pjax></form>").appendTo($(mygrid));
   $form.submit();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.